# How to show data from flows on Google map

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

*the codes are in [github](https://github.com/NakaoKisho/clean-architecture)

I'm creating an earthquake map app.
The app gets earthquake info from 2 web APIs and shows the location on Google map.
In MainScreen.kt, it gets data list and put marker on the map by using forEach().

###### MainScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val items = viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    if (items.value is MainActivityUiState.Success) {
        MainScreen((items.value as MainActivityUiState.Success).earthquakeData)
    } else {
        val noItemList = emptyList<EarthquakeInfo>()
        MainScreen(noItemList)
    }
}

@Composable
internal fun MainScreen(
    items: List<EarthquakeInfo>
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        Column {
            val tokyo = LatLng(35.6812, 139.7671)
            val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
                position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(tokyo, 0f)
            }

            GoogleMap(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
            ) {
                items.forEach {
                    Marker(
                        position = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude),
                        title = it.place,
                        snippet = it.place
                    )
                }
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

###### MainViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    usgsEarthquakeRepository: UsgsEarthquakeRepository,
    p2pquakeRepository: P2pquakeRepository,
    @DefaultDispatcher defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
) : ViewModel() {
    val uiState: StateFlow<MainActivityUiState> =
        try {
            GetLatestEarthquakeInfoUseCase(
                usgsEarthquakeRepository,
                p2pquakeRepository,
            )
                .invoke()
                .flowOn(defaultDispatcher)
                .map<List<EarthquakeInfo>, MainActivityUiState>(::Success)
                .stateIn(
                    scope = viewModelScope,
                    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
                    initialValue = MainActivityUiState.Loading,
                )
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            MutableStateFlow(MainActivityUiState.Error).asStateFlow()
        }
}

sealed interface MainActivityUiState {
    object Loading: MainActivityUiState
    data class Success(val earthquakeData: List<EarthquakeInfo>): MainActivityUiState
    object Error: MainActivityUiState
}
```

In GetLatestEarthquakeInfoUseCase.kt, it needs to merge data from the APIs but they have different data structures so I use map() to create EarthquakeInfo data class and put necessary data.
And then it uses merge to return data list.

###### GetLatestEarthquakeInfoUseCase.kt

```
class GetLatestEarthquakeInfoUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val usgsEarthquakeRepository: UsgsEarthquakeRepository,
    private val p2pquakeRepository: P2pquakeRepository,
) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<List<EarthquakeInfo>> {
        val usgsEarthquakeFlow =
            usgsEarthquakeRepository
                .getInfo("geojson", 20, "time")
                .map { usgsEarthquakeInfo ->
                    usgsEarthquakeInfo.features
                        .map { feature ->
                        EarthquakeInfo(
                            feature.properties.getDatetime(),
                            feature.properties.place ?: "",
                            feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
                            feature.geometry.coordinates[0],
                            feature.properties.mag,
                            feature.geometry.getDepth(),
                        )
                    }
                }

        val p2pEarthquakeFlow =
            p2pquakeRepository
                .getInfo(10, 0)
                .map { p2pquakeInfo ->
                    p2pquakeInfo.map { data ->
                        EarthquakeInfo(
                            data.earthquake.getDatetime(),
                            data.earthquake.hypocenter.name,
                            data.earthquake.hypocenter.latitude,
                            data.earthquake.hypocenter.longitude,
                            data.earthquake.hypocenter.magnitude,
                            data.earthquake.hypocenter.depth,
                        )
                    }
                }

        return merge(usgsEarthquakeFlow, p2pEarthquakeFlow)
    }
}
```

When I run the code, it shows markers from p2pEarthquakeFlow for like 1 sec and disappears and then shows markers from usgsEarthquakeFlow.
I would like to show both but it shows only usgsEarthquakeFlow data eventually.
Could you please help me?


I'm newbie to android Kotlin and English is my secondary language so if I make mistakes, let me know. 
I will fix it.

Comment: Put logs in `p2pEarthquakeFlow`, `usgsEarthquakeFlow`; after `GetLatestEarthquakeInfoUseCase.invoke()`, see if List<> inside Flow is as expected. If no, you will find exact problem location. If yes, then check Composables

Comment: I put logs under "val items = viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()" in MainScreen.kt and it shows list data from p2p first and then usgs. I think this causes marker to re-compose so the app shows p2p first and delete them all. After that, it shows usgs data.

Answer (score 0):

As this [article](https://kt.academy/article/cc-flow-combine#:%7E:text=It%20is%20important%20to%20know%20that%20when%20we%20use%20merge%20the%20elements%20from%20one%20flow%20do%20not%20wait%20for%20another%20flow.) says, merge() doesn't wait for another flow.
When I put

```
println(items.value)
```

under

```
val items = viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

in MainScreen.kt this shows data from P2P and USGS alternately.
This causes re-compose of Marker() in MainScreen.kt which shows P2P data first and delete them and then shows USGS data.

I changed repositories to return List<> and in usecase changed to create EarthquakeInfo data from both List<> and then emit(List<> + List<>)